# Android SearchView disable/hide QuickSearchBox/Suggestion

Tags: android, search, searchview

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.
I've already read some post here on stackoverflow and around the web, i've read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/), but i can't figure out how to hide or prevent the box to expand under the searchview when i tap on it.
Look the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Ox5.png) for a better explanation.
For the implementation i've:

**searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
android:includeInGlobalSearch="false"
android:searchSuggestSelection="null"/>
```

**search_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" /></menu>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable">
        </meta-data>
<intent-filter
    ...
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
```

and the implementation of `onCreateOptionsMenu` like this

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // perform query here
            query = Uri.encode(query);
            // workaround to avoid issues with some emulators and keyboard devices firing twice if a keyboard enter is used
            // see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24599
            searchView.clearFocus();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Does it have the same behaviour with just ifRoom?

Comment: @JonathanI yes, changing that value doesn't change the result :(